# Conditional formatting on entire row for grouping

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an excel report which is grouped by person i.e. The persons name is in the first cell and then all person child data is in this row and subsequent rows.  All subsequent rows of the person has the first cell blank.  A new person then has the first cell populated again.

I am trying to acheive something similar to a grid with alternate row colours per person wherein the first rows for person 1 maybe highlighted and the second row is not, third person is highlighted and so on and so on.

Can this be handled by conditional formatting?

Thanks

Comment: No need for conditional formatting. Next to conditional formatting there's a section called "format as table". Format that section as a table.

Comment: @HilaDG formatting as a table will alternate the color each row, without looking if it is a new person

Answer (score 0):

This answers assumes you don't want to use VBA, but only conditional formatting, hence, the solution is limited, but this may be enough. If you will to write some code, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148009/conditional-format-based-on-the-first-word/38425927#38425927) for anthor option.

The basic idea is to create a color-code by the first letters in the person's name, I choose to take the first 3 letters, but you can take more if you wish. So I use a helper column (`code`) with the formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A1,CODE(LEFT(B2,1))+CODE(MID(B2,2,1))+CODE(MID(B2,3,1)))
```

which is then dragged to the end of the table. Then you use some color-range conditional formatting to format all cells in this column based on their values.

[image: Formatting by text]

Tell me if it solved your problem ;)